# Browser Websocket client error (opcod -1) when connecting to a node backend with socket.io

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, socket.io

```
const sock = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:3000/');
```

gives me opcode -1 error in chrome.

The server runs node and socket.io. If i use socket.io-client , it works just fine, but i want to use the native browser socket implementation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: it turns out socket io works only with its own client , not with browser socket client

Comment: what do you mean by its own client, can you please elaborate or post your solution?... I am already using socket.io-client but still get this Opcod -1 and error in console saying Invalid Frame Header. Did you get the same, if so how did you solve it?

Comment: in my case ,(  when i was getting this error ) was using socket.io on the server side and native socket on frontend. my fix was simply using native socket on both sides.

Comment: Would you mind revealing socket-io version both on server and client. Thanks.

Comment: i am not using socket io anymore , just native socket. it works just fine for my use case (https://github.com/websockets/ws for node backend , and native browser ws for frontend)

Comment: I guess I am going to give up socket.io too, I could not solve this problem and it is always falling back to long polling. Wasted too much time on this. Thanks anyways. Though interested to know your reason to get away from socket.io